# Android and AWS Cognito - Unable to unmarshall error response with proguard

Tags: android, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, android-proguard

I am using the AWS cognito SDK for Android, version 2.4.3. It works perfectly fine on debug version, but on release versions, in case of error, I cannot get a proper description on the exception. Instead, I get this

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (<init> [class java.lang.String]). Response Code: 400, Response Text: Bad Request
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class java.lang.String]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
    at com.amazonaws.transform.AbstractErrorUnmarshaller.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.transform.InvalidParameterExceptionUnmarshaller.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.b(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool.a(Unknown Source) 
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUserPool$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

On debug version I get an exception indicating in detail the error. However, in both release and debug user registration succeeds in case all fields are well written. I am using proguard on release and I am aplying the rules from  [this file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/Proguard.md)

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After trying different Proguard settings, following is the minimal configuration, additional to that suggested on AWS SDK repository, to make it work

```
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.** { *; }
```

it must be added to `app/proguard-rules.pro`

Answer (score 4):

Unmarshalling errors can also occur with classes in the AWS core library, not just `com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider`.  This rule will prevent this crash for all AWS lib exceptions:

```
-keep class * extends com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException { *; }
```